# Help identifying a Kanji character from image

Tags: words, kanji, readings, reading-comprehension

I've been struggling to identify this Kanji for 30 minutes now. Tried looking up radicals, stroke order, etc. but can't figure it out.

[image]

More context:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used this [website](https://kanji.sljfaq.org/radicals.html) and noticed the left hand side looked like the child radical 子, then counted the strokes as 10 and found [this](http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1MMJ%E5%AD%AB)　孫｛まご｝. Which has a kun-yomi that matches the furigana next to it as まご, the website lists the meaning as grandchild/descendent

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but more importantly, thank you for explaining your approach. I'll add this approach to my arsenal!

Comment: Excellent job explaining the process for looking it up!  These skills are critical for new learners to develop.

Comment: This website is super helpful, though sometimes it does take a little playing around to identify exactly which radicals the kanji is classified with, and exactly how many strokes their are. Though usually one or two radicals is enough to lower the amount of possible kanji from thousands to tens