# What is this kanji in the image?

Tags: meaning, kanji

I have been trying to find the meaning of this kanji for 2 hours now.
What does it mean?

[image: kanji]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kanji is [堂{どう}](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A0%82) (*dō*), and it usually means *hall* or *temple* when used in compounds (words that contain multiple kanji characters), for example 食堂{しょくどう} (*shokudō*, dining hall, canteen) and 講堂{こうどう} (*kōdō*, lecturing hall, auditorium).

The character usually doesn't appear on its own, so I'm curious to see the full image if you have it.

Here's a trick from [an answer to a similar question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/68692/39516): you can use [this tool](https://kanji.sljfaq.org/mr.html) to select kanji *radicals* (building blocks of kanji) in the character you're trying to find. For 堂, I selected the 土 and 口 radicals and then looked for it in the list of potential matches.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ev7vwua.png
this is the full image. It is a shop of a mechanic in an anime.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense.

Comment: The screenshot is from an anime called Gintama in which it is the shop of the best mechanic in edo. Its the sign of his shop. The owner's name is Gengai.

Comment: also thanks for the trick, its a lot easier to find some kanji's now